# how to check whether hamcrest.jar is installed in my pc

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

I'm trying to test few units using JUnit plugged with Ant in Eclipse IDE. And i'm getting the below error.

```
test:
[junit] Testsuite: TestMessageUtil
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
[junit] Testcase: initializationError(TestMessageUtil): Caused an ERROR
[junit] org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
[junit] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
[junit]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[junit] Test TestMessageUtil FAILED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Please help. I know I have to include hamcrest.jar in my classpath. But from where i can find that jar file?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/downloads/list

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks for the link. Do you know any ways to checking whether already available in my pc?

Comment: Use Ctrl + Shift + T on eclipse and type in org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing if it is not found that means you don't have the jar in your eclipse build path. 
I see that you are using ant to run tests. make sure the jar is in your ant classpath ( As Ant doesn't look at your eclipse classpath straight away)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I downloaded it and added it into my class path (Reference libraries in my project) But still the error remains the same.

Comment: @Girish You are correct. I tried that way. But it didn't show me the class. Please help me how to include that into my eclipse build path?

Comment: Moving into answer as comment doesn't format

Comment: Are you using hamcrest-all-1.3.jar ?

Comment: @robermann i'm using hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are having problems at runtime, so change its classpath's configuration:

1. Right click on your file (either junit or ant)
2. Run as -> Junit (or Ant)
3. Add `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` as an external jar among the user entries
4. Finally retry the run

[image]

Comment: yeah i done everything..!! but it didn't work. Till i change the project location to the C:/

Answer (score 1):

- Download the jar
- Go to Eclipse Project -> rt click -> Properties -> Java Build Path
- Click on Libraries tab -> Add External jar
- Browse to your downloaded location and add the jar
- To your ant use

Where dependence.lib points to the folder containing required jars

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
                <fileset dir="${dependecies.lib}">
                    <include name="*.jar" />
                </fileset>
        </path>
```

Comment: i have included the hamcrest.jar to the eclipse build path. But when i search for that class.. it doesn't show up.

Comment: check your jar, I have that class as part of hamcrest-core-1.3.jar.
Try to open and see in your hamcrest jar.
Also if you use JUnit 4.0, hamcrest core comes as part of the JUnit jar itself.

Comment: everything set.. And the same version only me too having. Can't make out where the problem is..

Comment: I found the problem. It was with the file location of my project. Actually it was in the D:/ drive and ones i moved the project location to the C:/ drive it worked fine.